# How to use Django Rest API for Video streaming Android application?

Tags: android, django, android-studio, django-rest-framework, exoplayer

I am building an application that uploads and stores user-generated video content and that content is accessible to a few people in his network. I am writing a Django based REST API for the same.

I have to explore how to stream video content in an Android application and find out about the Exoplayer. But it asks for a URL of video file to run. I don't want to make the URL public(that can be accessed by anyone if he knows the URL), rather I want to authenticate the user first and check if he has access or not and then only make person stream that video. So, I have been searching a lot but couldn't find how to input a get request in Exoplayer or any media player on android.

Can someone please help me point towards the documentation for the same. Basically, I will be working in Django to get the desired video file. Also, is there something different I will have to do from the Server side to handle this issue.

Edit: Also, I wanted to know if I am returning the complete file in Django Rest API, will Exoplayer(or any other player) be able to stream if I seek to a time on player which hasn't been downloaded yet. Basically, will these player manage seeking part if API returns whole file at a single time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you storing the video file? I would recommend using a cloud storage service like Amazon S3, which would be much cheaper than getting more space on your application servers. Then, you can build you own S3 file url to user mapping in your Django app and control access however you want (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: Thanks @slider for your help. I will be storing it on amazon aws only. Can you tell me how to control access to those urls based on user? Maybe point me to some documentation. I can think of only GET request as a way to do it, where first I check whether the user has access and then only return file as response. I am new to backend so thins might be a naive problem. Thanks.

Comment: @hardik24 I added an answer with a possible solution. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a rough outline of a possible design. I don't know the details of your project so I'm making many assumptions. If you're using S3, you would want to use the [boto](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) client. But before that, make sure all files in your bucket are private. Get an access key for you app so that you can make API calls to S3. Then, once you have all this, you could so something like this:

Create a new `videofile` app and define a `VideoFile` model:

```
import boto3 as boto
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class VideoFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    content_key = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def generate_download_url(self, ):
        s3 = boto.client('s3')
        url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': settings.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
                'Key': self.content_key
            }
        )
        return url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What does this do? It creates a table that stores S3 file ids (in the `content_key` column) and each file has an `owner` which is a foreign key to the User object in your django app. `generate_download_url` generates presigned urls that expire after a while.

To upload a new video to S3, perhaps something like:

```
def create_document(file_object, key_name, owner):
    try:
        s3 = boto.resource('s3')
        s3.Object(settings.S3_BUCKET_NAME, key_name).put(Body=file_object)
    except Exception, err:
        print("Could not create object in s3")
        return
    video_file = VideoFile.objects.create(owner=owner, name=file_object.name, content_key=key_name)
    return video_file
```

Finally, you can perform the "is_friend_of()" check in the appropriate DRF view and return the temporary url.

```
class FileStreamUrl(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        my_man = User.objects.get(...)
        if request.user.is_friend_of(my_man):
            video_file = some_user.objects.video_file_set.filter(...)
            url = video_file.generate_download_url()
            return Response(url)
        else:
            return Response(status=403) # Forbidden
```

Comment: Thanks @slider for the answer, it was all I was looking for. Just one thing, if the url(temporary) gets exposed to someone, won't it be accessible to all? Is there a way to secure that further?

Comment: That's the only way I know of. Perhaps you can find something here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html